# Read server-side JavaScript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JS library file of variables (caption strings) used by *server-side* JavaScript. Can I read/interpret that from PHP?

The path to the data isn't the issue, but whether PHP can read/use the JS variables. Currently I've the same variable stored in both a JS file and PHP include with obvious scope for changes getting out of synch. I've tried reading the PHP from the *server-side* JS without joy but was wondering if - with suitable parsing - if PHP could extract/use the JS variables.

I repeat *all* data involved is *server-side* on the same server. Sorry if I've missed this being answered before but PHP/JS questions are (even if mis-titled) seemingly all about passing data between client and server side processes - which isn't my scenario.

Later - clarification:

The s/s JavaScript is part of a web interface to an image database where I can't alter the API. It doesn't support creating emails (for file requests) thus I am having to do that via PHP. Work scope/budget precludes re-writing a new d/b interface, rather we 'just' ned to be able to send an email. IOW, I realise you wouldn't choose to be trying to do this if starting from scratch! Also, I don't think I can do s/side AJAX to fetch variables or do PHP smtp mail as the JS environment seemingly isn't designed for that degree of s/s processing pre HTML page delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have config values (ie the captions) in the JS code.

If you want to keep it this way, my suggestion would be to split the config itself into a discrete .JS file, which would contain just the variable definitions but no actual JS code.

Then you should be able to simply parse it in PHP using `json_decode()`. Job done.

Comment: Yes, this should work - I may need to add JSON decode routines for the s/s JS, but that's OK. I'll also need to re-write the current library of variables slightly but that's also not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can interact with JavasScript via the [V8js library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php)

Comment: Isn't that a PHP based runtime for javascript? Not a way that his current server side runtime for javascript could communicate with PHP scripts?

Comment: @JimboJonny — His current server side runtime is PHP. He wants to use it to run JS.

Comment: not so sure that's true, statements like *"I've tried reading the PHP from the server-side JS without joy"* imply he is already running both JS and PHP server environments and is currently trying to get communication between them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format. If your file is anywhere near to JSON and publicly accessible (or at least on the same server with PHP), you could do something like:

File `test.js`:

```
var data = {
    'Hello': 'L-ghodwa it-tajba',
    'Bye':   'Caw',
}
```

File `reader.php`:

```
<?php

    $data = file_get_contents('test.js'); // or http://url.to/test.js
    $data = str_replace('var data = ', '', $data);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    print_r($data);

?>
```

This system is also pretty efficient; it is about manipulating a string a little bit and parsing it as JSON instead of having a full-blown JS parser. However, you have to enforce the format of the js file.

**Edit:** Yea, well, seems Spudley got first a few seconds before mine. Basically, I'm doing what he suggested.

**Edit 2:**  I've been thinking, you can simply make use of JSON files. These *must* contain JSON, so the format is already there; and you can use the same file through JS and PHP without problems or afterthoughts. JSON files end with a `.json` extension, by the way. You might need to tell your webserver what mimetype json is, using (Apache/htaccess):

```
AddType application/json .json
```

Comment: Gave Spudley the tick for suggesting JSON, but thanks for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that most answer in the client/server case involves JSON. What is stopping you from using the same method, albeit with the js script running on the server?

You could store these variables in a file in JSON, and have both the JS script and the PHP script load them.
Of course, your PHP installation must support JSON to begin with.

Comment: Oops, missed this in scrolling. JSON looks the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using either pretty complex regular expressions if you are trying to parse a JS file in PHP, or you should be creating an API which will allow communicating between JS scripts (e.g. in Node) and PHP.

Question is, why do you need to do this in exact this fashion? Why can't you share data in a format that can be used by both JS and PHP? JSON, for example.

Comment: Any language syntax could have a server runtime created for it to be run server side. I believe the OP is talking about an environment that runs javascript syntax code on the server side. Considering JS's popularity I'd bet there's many environments for it to be used that way. I don't think it has anything to do with running JS code by parsing it with PHP. They just wants some communication between some JS server side scripts and some PHP server side scripts.